# Proof reading service

Tags: collaboration, process

I am looking for a proof reading service for my scientific paper. I am not a native English speaker. I have spent significant time on improving the writing, thus I want to try a proof reading service.

I would like to go for Editage (http://www.editage.com/) but, before I do that, I would like to learn what other providers/company you use and could recommend.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding professional services.  See the [help center](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a copyeditor who specializes in academic writing, if possible one that specializes in journals.

Please also note that, when the writer's first language isn't English, some journals *require* ESL editing before acceptance.

Comment: I am not native English, so for me I need somebody who checks the correctness of my writing. The grammar mistakes are quite  destructive for the credibility of any type of writing.

Comment: That's what ESL editing is, it's specifically designed to correct errors made by non-native English speakers. But they also need to know academic writing, and whatever style standards the target journal requires.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a new business/technical writing/editing company, and I think we can help. We offer an editing and proofreading service. Take a look: http://www.thediamondpen.com/editing.html

Comment: Welcome.  The occasional post that references, where it actually makes sense, your business is allowed, as long as that is not all you post here.  Also you need to state your affiliation, as you've done.  Thanks for following our guidelines!

Answer (score -1):

[Grammarly](http://www.grammarly.com/) works great for usage, grammar, spelling, etc. (and it's free).

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't tell you exactly where the problem is; only general info in the free version so I's advise against it if the OP wants to improve his writing not only know there's something wrong with it... Or he can purchase an account.

Comment: The free version does not provide any information how good or how bad is the service. It is a pity.

Answer (score -2):

I am a proofreader at Hollywood and proofread all kind of scripts. I have 18 years of experience.. you can contact me if you would like to proofread your material.

Regards,
Lena Banks
http://www.TheBitchWithTheRedPen.com